# If I send a ruby on rails version 5.2 project via zip file to someone will my encrypted credentials still work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a coding project(using rails 5.2) for an interview that contains API calls that uses secret keys. I am used to older version of rails before the encrypted credentials were added in and not entirely sure how they work. If I use the encrypted credentials to store my keys and then send my project over to share, if they open the project in their local environment will my code that receives the api calls still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption and decryption of the credentials is dependent on the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` which is stored in `config/master.key`.

This shouldn't be put into version control, but I am guessing if you are sending a zip file of the whole directory, then that `config/master.key` should still be there and anyone who unzips the project file will be able to decrypt the credentials.